# How do I optimize an abstract syntax tree?

Tags: python, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, lexer, parse-tree

I'm trying to create a script in python that given an input string like a+a*b, reads it, parses it, and creates an abstract syntax tree.

At this point, the AST should have tokens and be something like
(Var_A, PLUS, (Var_A, MUL, Var_B)).

I managed to do everything until here and now I should optimize the AST and get in output something that has **as few variable as possible**, so having an output like (b+1)*a

Does anyone know an algorithm or a code that will do this sort of optimization?

Ps. I can't use any external library, I have to implement this from zero

Comment: Your AST library should provide ways to add, remove, or edit nodes in the tree. It's up to you to write a function that, given one AST, returns a new AST with new structure. For example, you have to examine the node, and if its children have the appropriate values, you can construct a new, equivalent node. In this case you can replace `(Var_A, PLUS, (Var_B, MUL, ...))` (it doesn't matter what the other argument to `MUL` is) with `(Var_A, MUL, (Literal_1, PLUS, Var_B))`.

Comment: It's for a project in university and I cant use any library, do you have any suggestions? Also how to find in the tree the thing that I have to optimize?

Comment: "as few variable as possible" - but `(b+1)*a` has the exact same amount of variables as `a+a*b` (`a` and `b`), the same number of leaf nodes, the same depth _and_ the same number of operations, so these expressions are basically the same.

Comment: @ForceBru The repeated use of `a` has been replaced by a constant; that's *kind* of an optimization :)

Comment: The question as it stands is too broad. You are building the AST yourself, and if your question isn't around how to do that, then it's a fairly open question about what optimizations you want to make, and doing them is just a matter of manipulating the tree however your code allows you to do that.

Comment: To wit: there's no single algorithm for these optimizations; it's just manipulating the tree in whatever way *you* think constitutes an optimization.

Comment: [This paper](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~kastner/papers/iccad04-subexpr_polynomials.pdf) is maybe a bit advanced for the course you're doing, but it has a good set of references which you could follow. It popped up as the first response to a web search for "compiler optimization algebraic factoring". Basically, the question is so open-ended that you could spend as much time as you had available adding more and more optimizations.

Comment: YES! it's a very broad, that's why I basically don't know well what to do. 
The professor just wrote "Minimize the number of usage of elements in arrays" and gave the example of a+a*b -> (b+1)*a

Comment: That's something to discuss with your professor. However, `(b + 1) * a` is an improvement in the sense that you don't have to access the value of `a` twice.